# Validation on cjuidialog modal window

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, yii

I have a similar similar solution as posted on the wiki
[here](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/72/cjuidialog-and-ajaxsubmitbutton)

But i'm unable to have my validation rules working as expected. When I click on the submit buttom the modal window closes and nothing is saved if I don't fill all the required fields.

Any idea of what i'm missing here? I have ajax validation "on" on the action and also on the view.

Here's some pieces of my code:

model Institution.php

```
        public function actionAddnew() {
        $model=new Institution;
        // Ajax Validation enabled
        $this->performAjaxValidation($model);
                $flag=true;
        if(isset($_POST['Institution']))
        {       $flag=false;
            $model->attributes=$_POST['Institution'];

            if($model->save()) {
                //Return an <option> and select it
                            echo CHtml::tag('option',array (
                                'value'=>$model->id,
                                'selected'=>true
                            ),CHtml::encode($model->name),true);
                        }
                }
                if($flag) {
                    Yii::app()->clientScript->scriptMap['jquery.js'] = false;
                    $this->renderPartial('createDialog',array('model'=>$model,),false,true);
                }
    }
```

file createDialog.php

```
<?php 
$this->beginWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog',array(
                'id'=>'institutionDialog',
                'options'=>array(
                    'title'=>Yii::t('institution','Institution'),
                    'autoOpen'=>true,
                    'modal'=>'true',
                    'width'=>'auto',
                    'height'=>'auto',
                ),
                ));
echo $this->renderPartial('_formDialog', array('model'=>$model)); ?>
<?php $this->endWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog');?>
```

and finally a piece from the _formDialog.php

```
    <div class="form" id="institutionDialogForm">

<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'institution-form',
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
)); 
?>

    <?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>


    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'name'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'name',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>255)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'name'); ?>
    </div>

....
    <div class="row buttons">
        <?php echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton(Yii::t('institution','Create'),CHtml::normalizeUrl(array('institution/addnew','render'=>false)),array('success'=>'js: function(data) {
                        $("#User_institutionid").append(data);
                        $("#institutionDialog").dialog("close");
                    }'),array('id'=>'closeInstitutionDialog')); ?>
    </div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>

</div>
```

Any idea? in this example I would like that the "name" that is already set as required on the rules to be required here as well. Note that on the default crud files that gii generates this is working ok. And I'm trying to implement a wizard with modal windows to add new itens while filling the wizards.

To be more clear, I would like to avoid submitting the modal window so that the required field(s) are asked to be filled before hitting the submit buttom on the modal window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you are closing the dialog according to the `success` of the ajax call and not on the success of validation, i.e the line:

```
$("#institutionDialog").dialog("close");
```

is always executed when your `ajaxSubmitButton` is clicked, regardless of validation state of form.

To close the dialog only when validation was successfully passed, you will have to change the `success` callback function of jquery ajax, and also the way that the form is processed in your controller action.

First, you have to detect if the model was successfully validated. To do this in your controller action, pass an additional field that indicates validation status:

```
if($model->save()) {
    echo CJSON::encode(
        array(
            'data' => CHtml::tag('option',array (
                          'value'=>$model->id,
                          'selected'=>true
                          ), CHtml::encode($model->name),true),
            'status'=>'success'
        )
    );
}
```

Then change your `ajaxSubmitButton`'s ajax options (namely the `success` callback, and `dataType`):

```
<?php echo 
    CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton(
        // ... old code
        array(
            'dataType'=>'json',
            'success'=>'function(data) {
                if(data != null && data.status == "success") {
                    $("#User_institutionid").append(data.data);
                    $("#institutionDialog").dialog("close");
                }

            }'),
        // ... old code
    ); 
?>
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help. I'm new this kind of approach and you made it very clear to me. Thank you. This solved my problem.